# how to give dynamic data from database into wow slider in jquery mobile

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

at present am using some static data into slider in wow slider jquery mobile. But i need to fetch the data from db and place it in silder. Can someone suggest me to do that thanks.
here is the new code am able to get the data in slider but there are buttons to which click functionality has to work but only for first slide it is working and remaining its not working please help me thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#like_i").click(function() {
            $("#tipid").val(1);
            $("#like_i").attr("src","images/ic_like_select.png");
            $("#unlike_i").attr("src","images/ic_unlike_unselect.png");
          });

          $("#unlike_i").click(function() {
            $("#tipid").val(0);
            $("#like_i").attr("src","images/ic_like_unselect.png");
            $("#unlike_i").attr("src","images/ic_unlike_select.png");
          });
          });
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
            <div id="back-btn">
                <a href="#" onClick="window.history.back();" ><img src="images/back_btn.png" width="42" height="41" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="tc-btn">
                <a href="terms.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/tc_btn.png" width="42" height="41" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content-area">


<br/>                   
                       <div id="wowslider-container1">
                      <form action="#" method="post">
                            <div class="ws_images">

                            <ul>
                            <?php

                             if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                                    $counter;
                                    foreach ($int_arr as $x) {


                                        if ($stmt1->execute(array($x))) {
                                           while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                                           // print_r($row);
                                           //echo $row1['title'];

                             ?>

                             <li><img src="engine1/bg.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1"/><div><span style="font-size:12px;text-transform:uppercase;"><b><?php echo $_GET['id'];?></b></span><br><span style="color:#3B8BD7;font-size:22px;"><?php echo $row1['title'];?></span></div><img src="images/list_hr.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-x;width:303px;height:4px;margin-top:-3px;" /><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $row1['body'];?><br><br><br></span><img src="images/list_hr.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-x;width:303px;height:4px;"/><div align="center"><b><p style="color:#3B8BD7;font-size:14px;">Helpline?</p></b><img src="images/ic_like_unselect.png" height="40" width="40" id="like_<?php echo $counter;?>" name="offer" />&nbsp;<img src="images/ic_unlike_unselect.png"  height="40" width="40" id="unlike_<?php echo $counter;?>"  name="offer"/></div>
                             <input type="hidden" name="tipid" id="tipid" value="" />
                             <input type="text" name="tip" id="tip" value="<?php  echo $counter;?>" /><?php $counter++;?></li>
<?php }}}}}  echo $counter;?>
                            </ul></div>
                            <div class="ws_bullets">
                            <div align="center">
                                <?php if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                                       foreach ($int_arr as $x) {
                                          if ($stmt1->execute(array($x))) {
                                          while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                                          // print_r($row);
                                          //echo $row1['title'];
                                ?>
                                <a href="#" ></a>
                                <?php }}}}}?>           
                            </div></div>

    <div class="ws_shadow">

                    </div>

        </form>         
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>                
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Fetch the data from db & put it into the right place. What have you tried so far ? Where have you being stuck exactly ?

Comment: i need some example to go through

Comment: i have added my code and issue in the question please check it

Comment: You do not require to use while loop two times. Just use it once & your problem will get solved.

Comment: if am using only once only one data is getting and dots is not working

Comment: please edit in my code

Comment: excuse me someone answer me please

Answer (score 2):

Fetch data from database and loop through the data and declare a variable `$counter` out outside of the loop then increment inside the loop

```
  <ul>
            <?php
            // Fetch data from database and loop through.
                     $counter;
            // start of the loop
            ?>
                <li><img src="data1/images/home.png" alt="" title=""
                    id="<?php echo $counter?>" /><?php echo $title?></li>
                <?php
                           $counter++;
                // End of the loop

                ?>
            </ul>
```

Comment: i have added my code and issue in the question please check it

Comment: Use `$counter` as suggested in answer `<img src="data1/images/home.png" alt="" title="" id="wows<?php echo $counter.'_'.$counter"/>`

Comment: i have edited in my code both issue and code please check it and help me please thanks.

Comment: This is how things work, I am not sure where is the exact issue. Can you give me a live demo on http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: hi noor for every li tag a like and unlike button was there and i have to make it work by using javascript but it is not working that is my issue please understand

Comment: hi noor for every slider the counter increases and the id for images also changes as like_0,like_1,like_2.........  i have to make the javascript functionality to work for all these, can you please guide me thanks.

Comment: If you are facing new issues, then ask new question

Comment: i asked but no one replied